# Ни уха ни рыла (ни ухом ни рылом)

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Когда хотят сказать, что кто-то ничего не понимает в вопросе, могут употребить выражение ***ни уха ни рыла*** либо ***ни ухом ни рылом*** ( как правильно?).
Выражение, на мой взгляд, достаточно грубое.

Интересно было бы узнать: при чем тут рыло и ухо — к понимаю какого-либо вопроса?
Откуда вообще пошло выражение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

От свиньи, имхо. Означает, что некто "ни ухом" (не слышал), "ни рылом" (не нюхал, не осязал) чего-то того, в чем вынужден или вызвался разбираться.
А свинья здесь напрашивается, поскольку именно она имеет достаточно выраженные признаки "уха" и "рыла". Хотя, в принципе, можно применить и к органам чувств любого млекопитающего, в т.ч. и человека.

При таком понимании вариант "ни ухом(,) ни рылом" выглядит более обоснованным.
Вот что касается запятой, то можно спорить — в зависимости от авторского восприятия степени идиоматичности.

Comment: Но в такой трактовке фразеологизм звучит слишком уж грубо, особенно, когда это говорится по отношению к другому, а не к себе.

Answer (score 1):

**Ни уха ни рыла: О человеке, который ничегошеньки не понимает в какой-либо сфере.   Например: Если не смыслишь в механике ни уха ни рыла, так нечего и соваться! Отойди и не лезь, я сам все сделаю! Теги: некомпетентный, несведущий, глупый, профан, темнота, ни бум-бум, дуб дубом.**

---

Из моего знания: на сегодня не найдено объяснение просхождения фразеологизма, принятого лингвистами.

Он обычно сопровожд. пометами: простореч., грубый.

Answer (score 1):

"Ни уха, ни рыла" - полное отсутствие признаков свиного мяса. Свиные уши и рыла - отходы разделки свиньи, используются для варки студня. В переносном значении выражает отсутствие понимания в указанной тематике, как если бы при варке студня не то что мяса, но и ухо или рыло не положили в кастрюлю. Ну, совершенно бестолковый повар :)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно "ни уха, ни рыла", то есть не отличать одно от другого, ничего не понимать.
"Не повёл ни ухом, ни рылом" - некорректное, корявое (если не сказать идиотское) выражение от мастера корявых выражений Солженицына, который, судя по всему, не знал, как правильно, вот и шарахнул, как получилось. Получилось паршиво.
Правильно "не повёл и ухом" и "не смыслить ни уха, ни рыла".

Comment: "Не смыслить ни уха, ни рыла" и "не отличать одно от другого" — разные вещи.

Answer (score 0):

Мне сдается, что это выражение перекликается со знаменитым: "Видит око, да зуб неймёт!"
У Даля приводится одна из поговорок: "Не вымем корова доит, а рылом, по корму".
Тем самым ни ухом ни рылом — это и не видел, и не слышал, ни на зуб, ни на вкус, ни на взгляд не пробовал.
Иными словами — не знаком совершенно (от слова совсем).
Ближайший синоним — ни бум-бум.

Answer (score -1):

*Первая версия.* Так говорят про сильно пьяного человека. "Не ведет ни ухом, ни рылом". То есть ничего не соображает. Да, достаточно грубо, но про свиноподобное существо ласково говорить не приходится!

*Вторая версия.* Домашнее животное, это может быть кто угодно от кошки до коровы, настолько старое и больное, что не откликается на кличку ("ни ухом"), не реагирует на еду ("ни рылом").

Answer (score -3):

У меня это выражение ассоциируется с "ни слуха, ни голоса". По крайней мере в таком смысле выражение употреблялось у нас в Нижнем Поволжье в годы моей юности. Хотя чаще говорили "медведь на ухо наступил". Возможно, это как-то связано с происхожением этого выражения.